# CURL post request extremly slow

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Here is the link to the full source code: http://git.tholden.no/fason-ans/auto-regnskap-wp/blob/master/auto-accounting-pmpro.php

When i execute the call to the curl function, the request takes about ten seconds to complete. The same request from POSTMAN, or probably any other
rest client takes a couple of ms.

Do anyone know what could be wrong?

Here is the specific function:

```
function execute_curl_request($headers = null, $data = null, $url, $type) {
    $send = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($send, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);

    curl_setopt($send, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if ($headers != null) {
        curl_setopt($send, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    if ($data != null) {
        curl_setopt($send, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    }

    // Exec the request and decode the result.
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($send));

    curl_close($send);

    return $result;
}
```

It is not DNS lookup that takes all the time. I have checked that with get_info().

The only huge numbers in the get_info array is starttransfertime which is 10 seconds.

Its not IPV6 issues, as I have tried disabling IPV6 in CURL_SETOPT.

I really dont know what more it could be. I have emailed the support for the API, and they say that everything is working fine, and I have tested from POSTMAN and it is fine... So.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is confirmed to be an API problem, and they are looking in to it. Thanks.

Comment: In curl CLI, you may want to get rid of the `Expect: 100-continue` header, by using `curl -H "Expect:"`. It will make it execute dramatically faster.